# Convert flat query results into a more defined table structure

Tags: python, mysql

I am using flask and mysql to create an API for a simple app of mine. I wasn't quite sure how to go about converting flat query results that join on a table with 1-to-many relationships into a table structured json object.

Here is an example of the query I would like to execute. Each recipe may have many directions and many ingredients.

```
SELECT r.id
  , r.name
  , r.description
  , rd.text
  , ri.name
  , ri.amount
FROM recipes r 
LEFT JOIN recipe_directions rd ON rd.recipe_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON ri.recipe_id = r.id
```

And I'd like to turn the flat results of this query into a json object like the following. Is there something already baked into the mysql connector or flask that I could utilize to accomplish this?

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Recipe 1',
  description: '...',
  directions: [{
    text: 'Cook the rice'
  },
  {
     text: 'Do the next step...'
  }],
  ingredients: [{
    name: 'Rice',
    amount: '1 cup'
  },
  { 
    name: 'Onion',
    amount: '1'  
  }]
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Recipe 2',
  description: '...',
  directions: [...]
  ingredients: [...]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`GROUP_CONCAT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). That will allow you to return multiple records from the joined tables in each returned row.You will still have to do some formatting, but that will let you return each recipe as one record with it's directions & ingredients.

You might also want to consider using a package like [records](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records) with it's `.as_dict()` function to make things a little easier for yourself.